# Bitwise Operators in C, int 021 vs 21?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I have a C programming exam a few days later, in the sample that I was given, there is a problem about bitwise operators. Now I know &, |, ^, <<, >> and what they do.
But I am kind of confused about this:

```
int main()
{
int i = 021, j = 0x2A, k,l,m;
k = i | j;
l = i & j;
m = k ^ l;

printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",i,j,k,l,m);

return 0;
}
```

When I test it, the output is:
17 42 59 0 59

But I don't understand how. What is 021 in binary? 
If I take it as 21, (if I delete the 0 before it, the output changes completely.)
Can anyone help please?

Comment: When you use a leading zero and it is _not_ `0x` (which denotes hex), then `021` is _octal_, which is 17 decimal or `0x11` (hex). It may be more helpful if your `printf` uses `%x` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is 021 in binary? If I take it as 21, (if I delete the 0 before it, the output changes completely.)

An integer literal beginning with `0` is an octal number. If you remove the `0`, it is a decimal number. So the value of `021` is `2 * 8 + 1` which is `17`. The binary representation is `10001`.

If `0` is removed, the value of `i` is `21` and the binary representation is `10101`.
So the output changes accordingly when used in different operations.

Since you are using the conversion specifier `d` in your printf statement, all the values printed will be decimal.